# unity выдает ошибку при импорта vuforia

Tags: unity3d, vuforia

Здравствуйте при импорта vuforia на unity у меня выдает ошибку

error CS1704: An assembly with the same name `Vuforia.UnityExtensions' has already been imported. Consider removing one of the references or sign the assembly
C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/VuforiaSupport/Managed/Runtime/Vuforia.UnityExtensions.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
Assets/Vuforia/Scripts/Internal/Vuforia.UnityExtensions.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)

Что можно здесь сделать?

Помогите я в unity новичок

Comment: Ну если бы ты в переводчик запихал, то сразу понятно стало бы. У тебя дублируется логика, описанная в .dll , ты добавил ассет, который уже есть у Unity. Ну либо ты свой dll выпиливаешь, либо у Unity попробуй удалить из папки(путь есть)

Comment: я там ничего не дублировал это первая моя попытка импорта

Comment: что удалить? UnityExtension.dll?

Comment: именно так Vuforia.UnityExtensions.dll

Comment: не помогло? удалил и снова поставил

Comment: Удалил откуда и что/куда поставил?

Comment: я этот Vuforia.UnityExtensions.dll  удалил не помогло и потом вернул обратно на место

Comment: Откуда удалял то, из папки с юнити или из проекта?

Answer (score 1):

Может быть поздно, но все же. В новых версиях unity есть встроенная vuforia support, которая устанавливается с юнькой, в общем, нужно зайти в Player Settings -> XR -> Vuforia Support AR поставить галочку и юнька импортирует сама вуфорию. Скачивать ее и в ручную импортирвать не нужно.